# Onclick events on buttons

Tags: javascript

New to Javascript and haven't used it for over a few months so I'm trying to refresh my memory but I'm stuck with my buttons and onclick not working properly. I'm just building a simple rock paper scissors game that prompts the user to say how many rounds they would like to play and then they hit the buttons and then at the end tells them how many times they won and the computer. I realize this is pretty rough code but it's hard to keep moving on when the buttons aren't working properly. I would appreciate any help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
    var rounds = prompt("How many rounds would you like to play?");

    function rpsGame(playerChoice) {
    var playerWins = 0;
    var cpuWins = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < rounds.length; i++) {

        function cpuChoice() {
            var randomNumber = Math.random();
            if (randomNumber < 0.33) {
                return 'rock';
            } else if (randomNumber <= 0.66) {
                return 'paper';
            } else {
                return 'scissors';
            }
        }

        function whoWins(playerChoice, cpuChoice) {
            var combination = playerChoice + cpuChoice;
            var result;
            switch (combination) {
                case 'rockscissors':
                    result = "Player wins";
                    break;
                case 'rockpaper':
                    result = "Computer wins";
                    break;
                case 'scissorsrock':
                    result = "Computer wins";
                    break;
                case 'scissorspaper':
                    result = "Player wins";
                    break;
                case 'paperrock':
                    result = "Player wins";
                    break;
                case 'paperscissors':
                    result = "Computer wins";
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "Tie!";
                    break;
            }
            return result;

        }

        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = result;
    }

    if (playerWins > cpuWins) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = ("User won!");
    }
    if (userWins < cpuWins) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = ("Computer won!");
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <button onclick="rpsGame('rock')" id="button-1">Rock</button>
        <button onclick="rpsGame('paper')" id="button-2">Paper</button>
        <button onclick="rpsGame('scissors')" id="button-3">Scissors</button></p>
    <div id="msg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The buttons and the onClick function looks fine. Can you give sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like some variable names were wrong when you tried to call them plus some other thing as well.

Below is the edited version with some minor fixes. You were reeally close to getting it working, the onClick events were completely fine.

What i changed was this line `if (userWins < cpuWins)` to `if (playerWins < cpuWins)` since you never created a variable called userWins which i'm guessing you meant playerWins instead.

Also i changed this line `document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = result;` to `document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = whoWins(playerChoice, cpuChoice());`

You were never invoking the `whoWins()` function, therefore result was never instanced. What i did here was instead of assigning the value of result to the msg element i simply invoked the function `whoWins()`, which returns result, with its given parameters, in this case the user input stored in `playerChoice` and the cpu choice which was returned by invoking `cpuChoice()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
    var rounds = prompt("How many rounds would you like to play?");

    function rpsGame(playerChoice) {
    var playerWins = 0;
    var cpuWins = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < rounds.length; i++) {

        function cpuChoice() {
            var randomNumber = Math.random();
            if (randomNumber < 0.33) {
                return 'rock';
            } else if (randomNumber <= 0.66) {
                return 'paper';
            } else {
                return 'scissors';
            }
        }

        function whoWins(playerChoice, cpuChoice) {
            var combination = playerChoice + cpuChoice;
            var result;
            switch (combination) {
                case 'rockscissors':
                    result = "Player wins";
                    break;
                case 'rockpaper':
                    result = "Computer wins";
                    break;
                case 'scissorsrock':
                    result = "Computer wins";
                    break;
                case 'scissorspaper':
                    result = "Player wins";
                    break;
                case 'paperrock':
                    result = "Player wins";
                    break;
                case 'paperscissors':
                    result = "Computer wins";
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "Tie!";
                    break;
            }
            return result;

        }

        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = whoWins(playerChoice, cpuChoice());
    }

    if (playerWins > cpuWins) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = ("User won!");
    }
    if (playerWins < cpuWins) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = ("Computer won!");
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <button onclick="rpsGame('rock')" id="button-1">Rock</button>
        <button onclick="rpsGame('paper')" id="button-2">Paper</button>
        <button onclick="rpsGame('scissors')" id="button-3">Scissors</button></p>
    <div id="msg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your result variable like `var result='';`

in your code-

```
if (userWins < cpuWins) {   // userWins variable not defined in your code Are you sure about variable name ? 

    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = ("Computer won!");
}
```

if yes, difine variable `userWins` in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
var rounds = prompt("How many rounds would you like to play?");
function rpsGame(playerChoice){
    var playerWins = 0;
    var cpuWins = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < Number(rounds); i++) {
        result = whoWins(playerChoice, cpuChoice());
        document.getElementById('msg').textContent = result;
    }

    if (playerWins > cpuWins) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = ("User won!");
    }
    if (userWins < cpuWins) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = ("Computer won!");
    }

}

function cpuChoice() {
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    if (randomNumber < 0.33) {
        return 'rock';
    } else if (randomNumber <= 0.66) {
        return 'paper';
    } else {
        return 'scissors';
    }
}

function whoWins(playerChoice, cpuChoice) {
    var combination = playerChoice + cpuChoice;
    var result;

    switch (combination) {
        case 'rockscissors':
            result = "Player wins";
            break;
        case 'rockpaper':
            result = "Computer wins";
            break;
        case 'scissorsrock':
            result = "Computer wins";
            break;
        case 'scissorspaper':
            result = "Player wins";
            break;
        case 'paperrock':
            result = "Player wins";
            break;
        case 'paperscissors':
            result = "Computer wins";
            break;
        default:
            result = "Tie!";
            break;
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;

}
```